# how to convert string in to different columns python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have csv file , which have one column and inside this column have string , string contains many values , i want to convert this string in muultiple columns

here is example data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1':[{'A':2,'B':3,'c':2}]})
print(df)
                    column1
0  {'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'c': 2}
1  {'A': 3, 'B': 5, 'c': 10}
```

i want output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2],'B':[3],'c':[2]})
```

Comment: Is there any code that you tried out yet? Also, clarification is needed - Is the sample data you have provided just a string that looks like a dictionary  "{"A":2,"B":3,"c":2}"  like this?

Comment: my dataframe column 1 each row have this type of string values , i want to convert row string to columns

Comment: Can you post the actual data? Your 'example data' is a line of python code. If the data is a CSV file, post a screenshot or write an example of the actual raw data. It is difficult to understand what you have, and what you need from the info that you have provided.

Comment: @MilindSharma printed my data , please have look .

Comment: That's not example input, that's a recreation of your example output. It would be more useful to have a few lines of CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
pd.DataFrame([*df['column1'].apply(eval)])
```

Comment: my dataframe column 1 each row have this type of string values , i want to convert row string to columns @ziying35

Comment: pd.DataFrame([*df['column'].apply(eval)])

Comment: thanks , your solution works , my data have other column which have list of 16 values , i also want to convert this list to columns

Comment: Because I don't know the overall structure of your DataFrame, I can't give code suggestions, you can repost a more detailed post to help

Comment: in your solution what is the meaning of * ?

Comment: Unpack the operation result of df['column1'] to form a list of dictionaries

Answer (score -1):

First convert string that looks like dictionary to an actual dictionary

```py
import json

my_dict = json.loads(column1)
 
# Gives you {'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'c': 2}
```

Then convert that dictionary to a dataframe:

```py
pd.Dataframe([my_dict])
```

Comment: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Series   , your soultion givibg thus error